# 3 dimensional matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, normals

I have a normal map of size `m`x`n`x`3`, where each pixel has a normal vector {Nx, Ny, Nz}.
I want to rotate each normal vector independently by a rotation matrix. Let `R` be the rotation matrix of size `m`x`n`x`3`x`3`, where each pixel has a rotation matrix of size `3`x`3`.

I want to multiply rotation matrix at each pixel to the normal vector to get the rotated 
normal vectors. I am looking for an optimized way to do the task, as looping over each pixel may not be the best way.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try

```
res = sum( bsxfun(@times, map, R), 4 );
```

With `map` an `m`-by-`n`-by-`3` normal vectors, and `R` an `m`-by-`n`-by-`3`-by-`3` the rotation per vector.

Coming to think about it, you might need to use `permute`

```
res = sum( bsxfun(@times, map, permute(R, [1 2 4 3]) ), 4 ); % transposing the vectors
```

Or, as [Harshit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420161/harshit-agrawal) put it:

```
res = sum( permute( bsxfun(@times, map, R ), [1 2 4 3]), 4 ); % transposing the vectors
```

Comment: Hi Shai,
thanks for replying! The rotation I'm talking about is matrix multiplication, so for each pixel, I would like to find Rij * Nij, where Rij is the 3x3 rotation matrix of pixel (i,j) and Nij is the 3x1 normal vector of pixel (i,j), the result will be 3x1 rotated normal vector.

Is your solution doing the same? If yes, then please explain how is it being done. 
Regards,

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal then you can think of the matrix-vector multiplication `A*x` as `sum( bsxfun( @times, A, x' ), 2 )`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There's a small edit. We should permute it after applying bsxfun. Please see my edit.